# Search.php - return number of results but cannot loop through

Tags: wp-query, loop, search

I have a following search.php page (this is just the code required for problem presentation).

Why is my `$total_results` returning a number of posts found, but when I do a loop though it always print `No posts found` ?

```
<?php

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array('posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged);

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
     $query_split = explode("=", $string);
     $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} 
$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
$total_results = $search->found_posts; // this returns 50

?>


<?php if ($search->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($search->have_posts()) : $search->the_post(); ?>
    loop  through posts
<?php else : ?>
     No posts found.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: The only reason i can think of is that you're on page 6 in the query. Try doing `var_dump($search->posts);` & see if that's as expected

Comment: The number of result is 50 for given keyword, if I change the keywords I am search for the number of result is different.

Comment: @MridulAggarwal - `var_dump($search->posts);` comes back as `array(0) { }`

Comment: `array(0) { }` means no data is coming from the database. Check your `paged` parameter. 50 posts with 10 per page means the `paged` parameter can be 5 at max

Comment: try `var_dump( $search_query );`

Comment: I gave it a try on `MySQL & Apache` and works fine. The query returns nothing on `IIS7 & SQL 2008 R2`. So most probably the code itself is fine - M$ is at fault ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Query::found_posts` contains the number of matches to your query without taking into account limit and offset. limit is the max number of posts which can be display in an archive page and the offset depends on the `paged` parameter and is usually `($paged - 1) * $limit`.

So what you got is the number of results you would have gotten for your search query if you asked to get **all** the posts that match the search criteria.

If you need to know the number of the results for the specific query including the limit and offset you can simply do `$search->post_count`.

Comment: Don't use `count($search->posts)`. You can read the same from `$search->post_count`

Comment: edited as suggested

Comment: $search->post_count comes back with `0`. What is wrong with my query? I am searching for a tag name - tag has been used in couple of post, which I can see under `admin/post/tag` . I also added the `Search Everywhere plugin`

Comment: tag names are not part of normal search. search is performed in the title and content. I actually don't understand the question anymore, is it about how the search is performed or how to know how many results are there?

Comment: @MarkKaplun - the SQL server (DB Abstraction) was to be fault. The code was OK - meaning my question was wrong as I was expecting the code to be at fault.